# SCP file transfer file prioritization

Tags: bash, macos, automation, expect, scp

I have about 150+ folders with dates on them that I need to upload daily to different servers. I need the more recent folders prioritized during the upload as they are used the most and I can be worked on while the rest upload. The first time i run the script every folder must be downloaded from newest to oldest based on folder name. Here are some sample folder names:

```
2016-01-02  2016-01-02  2016-01-03  2016-01-04  2016-01-05  2016-01-06 
2016-02-07  2016-02-11  2016-02-13  2016-02-18  2016-02-23  2016-02-28  
2016-03-07  2016-03-16  2016-03-21
```

All of these folders are inside a folder named `Files` and when i run: `scp -r /Users/$username/Files server@192.168.1.120:/var/www/html/backups`
The folders with the older file names upload first. (example order: `2016-01-02,2016-01-02,2016-01-03`) My goal is to reverse this so the folders upload in the opposite order (example: `2016-03-21,2016-03-16,2016-03-07`) Is there any trick to do this? **Preferably using `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` my for my current script I do not have to type in my password everytime I run the command. Here is what I currently use:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set username [exec id -un]
spawn scp -r /Users/$username/Files root@192.168.1.123:.
#######################
expect {
 -re ".*es.*o.*" {
    exp_send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
 -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "password\r"
  }
}
interact
```

Comment: Not sure that you've actually asked a question here, but it sounds like you want `rsync`, not `scp`.

Comment: please update your Q to indicate if old folders have changed data (always/sometimes/never). If you want to skip folders that have already be sent then that is a different Q. Please clarify (in the body of your Q, I would prefer to delete this comment once you have a clear Q). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I added more detail. Hope that's sufficient

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to set up SSH keys to avoid having to enter your password?  [`man ssh-keygen`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen). And while you're in a documentation-reading mode, also `man ssh_config` and search for "ControlMaster".

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if scp has this feature but you can do it yourself by adding a small logic to it:

```
for folder in $(ls -t /Users/$username/Files); do
    sshpass -p <password> scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r /Users/$username/Files/$folder server@192.168.1.120:/var/www/html/backups
done
```

Comment: Might seem like a stupid question but is this python or in bash? @Waman

Comment: nope not at all! fair question! it is shell (bash) script

Comment: Now if only this was possible to do in an except script. So it could be automated to not need a password. (I can't use rsa keys) @Waman

Comment: Try with the edited one. sshpass will help you get through the interactive password prompt.

Comment: Congrats, your solution is #1 on the [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) list!

Comment: Awesome! thanks for linking me to that informative PIT FALL :) ! very informative. but since the folder name structure is fixed in this case, it would not have any adverse affect on this. Thanks again!